# Open Camera from within UITableView Cell

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimagepickercontroller

I've got a button in a custom Cell for a TableView which is supposed to open the camera for taking pictures.

I thought of two ways but can't get them working.
First one is to open an instance of UIImagePickerController from within the cell. Well, it seems like I can't call

```
[self presentViewController...];
```

from within the cell. Is this right?

Because of this "result" I thought of putting the method which opens up the UIImagePickerController inside the TableViewController and then call this method from within the cell (where the button is located) by something like

```
[super openCamera];
```

Or making the TableViewController the delegate of the cell to enable it to call the method.

Are these ideas going in the right direction? What would you recommend? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured something out but I'm still wondering if it can be done easier.
Here is the solution I found:

In the custom cell I added

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) id adminController;
```

Then in the tableViewController I customized the following method to use the custom cell I created and set the tableViewController als "admin"

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"cell";
    CreateCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.adminController = self;

    return cell;
}
```

So I could finally call

```
[self.adminController performSelector:@selector(openCamera)];
```

Comment: where to write this line [self.adminController performSelector:@selector(openCamera)]; ??

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I'd like to have my old questions answered too so... Yes, there is an easier way using blocks:

First, declare a public method in your UITableViewCell interface:

```
@interface YourCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *button;

- (void)setDidTapButtonBlock:(void (^)(id sender))didTapButtonBlock;

@end
```

In the UITableViewCell subclass implementation file declare a private property with a copy attribute.

```
#import "YourCell.h"

@interface YourCell ()

@property (copy, nonatomic) void (^buttonTappedBlock)(id sender);

@end
```

Add the target and action of the UIControl in the UITableViewCell constructor and implement the selector method

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];

    [self.button addTarget:self 
                    action:@selector(didTapButton:)  
          forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}

- (void)didTapButton:(id)sender {
    if (buttonTappedBlock) {
        buttonTappedBlock(sender);
    }
}
```

Finally implement the block code in the tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method in the controller

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
         cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    YourCell *cell = (YourCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier 
                                 forIndexPath:indexPath];

    [cell buttonTappedBlock:^(id sender) {
        NSLog(@"%@", item[@"title"]);
    }];

    return cell;
}
```

For further information in blocks, you can read [Working With Blocks](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html)